# angular.js capitalize each word

Tags: angularjs

This function should capitalize first letter for each word in input. But angular is throwing me "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded". And only becouse of that ' ' space on line 9.

```
myApp.directive('capitalizeFirst', function(uppercaseFilter, $parse) {
   return {
     require: 'ngModel',
     link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
        var capitalize = function(inputValue) {
           var capitalized = inputValue.split(' ').reduce(function(prevValue, word){
            return  prevValue + word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1)+' ';
        }, '');
           if(capitalized !== inputValue) {
              modelCtrl.$setViewValue(capitalized);
              modelCtrl.$render();
            }         
            return capitalized;
         }
         var model = $parse(attrs.ngModel);
         modelCtrl.$parsers.push(capitalize);
         capitalize(model(scope));
     }
   };
});
```

here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/YyYnM/205/

Can someone explain this to me? I'm trying to figure this out for an hour now.

Comment: It seems that `capitalized` will never equal the `inputValue`, because you are appending a space (` `) to the value in the reduce function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here

```
var capitalize = function(inputValue) {
           var capitalized = inputValue.split(' ').reduce(function(prevValue, word){
            return  prevValue + word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1)+' ';
        }, '');
```

It adds you an extra space every time you run  the function.

Angular works the way that it runs cycles.

Eeverytime a change of one of the variables is detected it runs another cycle.

Here because of the extra space, the string is changed in an infinite loop and therefore angular dies.

An ugly solution is to add afterwards

```
capitalized = capitalized.substring(0, capitalized.length - 1);
```

Comment: And what should I do when I'll modify split and space added to a letter with spaces? Like this var capitalize = function(inputValue) {
           var capitalized = inputValue.split(' b ').reduce(function(prevValue, word){
            return  prevValue + word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1)+' b ';
        }, '');

throws the same error

Comment: I would make something like this inputValue.split(' ').map(function(element){return  element.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + element.substring(1)}).join(' ');

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what's wrong with your code but try this. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YyYnM/216/)

```
myApp.directive('capitalizeFirst', function (uppercaseFilter, $parse) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            ngModel: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {

            scope.$watch("ngModel", function () {
                scope.ngModel = scope.ngModel.replace(/^(.)|\s(.)/g, function(v){ return v.toUpperCase( ); });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Your answer is great, but it throws undefined error when user clears all data. in order to avoid that, you can wrap your replace function like this 
if(typeof scope.ngModel !== 'undefined'){

scope.ngModel = scope.ngModel.replace(/^(.)|\s(.)/g, function(v){ return v.toUpperCase( ); });
            });
}

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the `''` on line 9 as you suggested, but your use of the `modelCtrl`. When you use `modelCtrl.$setViewValue` `modelCtrl` will run all the `$parsers` again. Therefore it will invoke your `capitalize` function recursivly until it rans out of stack.

All you need to do, to capitalize the input, is to push a function that changes the string to the `$parsers` array. This will do the job:

```
myApp.directive('capitalizeFirst', function(uppercaseFilter, $parse) {
   return {
     require: 'ngModel',
     link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
        var capitalize = function(inputValue) {
           var capitalized = inputValue.split(' ').reduce(function(prevValue, word){
            return  prevValue + word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1)+' ';
        }, '');        
            return capitalized;
         }
         modelCtrl.$parsers.push(capitalize);
     }
   };
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = '';
}
```

Comment: David Michael Gang is right. My solution will not capitalize the words inside the text box and his will.